# Changing projection and extent of raster using gdal

Tags: gdal, rasterio

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -t_srs "EPSG:4326" input.tif  output.tif
```

I want to change the projection of input.tif raster (from sinusoidal) and also its global extent to: top:90, left: -180, right:180, bottom:-90

How can I do this either using gdal or rasterio?

Comment: If you run `gdalsrsinfo input.tif`, does it report sinusoidal? Else you have to specify it with `-s_srs`.